# How to implement a word length frequency counter

Tags: java

> The field of text analysis makes use of many different tools in order
>   to extract information about written works. One of these methods is
>   word length frequency, which is used to assess patterns in writing
>   (for example, one author might prefer to use short, “snappy” words,
>   whilst another might prefer longer words). Such information can be
>   useful in helping to identify (or rule out) the author of an anonymous
>   piece of text, and it can also be used to improve the “flow” or
>   readability of text. In its simplest form, frequency analysis
>   calculates the number of words of length 1, 2, 3, ..., n, where n is
>   the length of the longest word in a given text. For example, analysing
>   the sentence “I am a man” would produce the output “2, 1, 1” (that is,
>   two words of length 1 ("I", "a"), one word of length 2 ("am") and one
>   word of length 3 ("man"). This assignment requires you to produce a
>   text-based application (i.e., a program that runs at the command line,
>   not a graphical program) which performs this analysis, calculating a
>   range of statistics on a piece of text. The specification for the
>   assignment is as follows:
>
> The program should read a file called body.txt, print it out, and
>   analyze its word-length frequency. For a "basic" (i.e. passing) mark,
>   you should count the frequencies of the word-lengths in the text and
>   show the results in text form (i.e., just list the frequencies).

So far i have got the code below and am really struggling as to how to progress, any pointers anyone could give would really help me. I'm new to this forum and coding itself so please don't insult me if this is a basic question.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Help1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    "body.txt"));
            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(text);
                // Work in this loop
                // The code takes each line in the file body.txt and
                // prints out each word
                String words[] = text.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("words[" + i + "]=" + words[i]);
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to insult you, but I am going to suggest that you read up about asking questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically, you need to include details about what the code should do (done, although very verbosely); what it does; why that is wrong; what you think the problem is; what you have done to try to debug it.

Comment: *"really struggling as to how to progress"* You're struggling with what exactly? You don't know what to do next or how to do the next part? Since you have each word (`words[i]`) you need to find its length (check the javaDoc of [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you may find something) and you need to store the length and the counter. So you need something that stores a combination of "unique things" (length of a word) with a "arbitrary thing" (the count of each word length), so you need something like "key-value pairs". Look around, you'll find something

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need a way to count the number of times that each word length occurs, don't you.  It's an assignment, so shame on anyone that just gives the answer, but this might help you think the problem through:

- You need a way to maintain a separate counter for each word length. 
  That sounds to me like a Map.  It would be indexed by the word length, and the value associated with each index entry would be the number of times that word length has occurred.
- Your first step would be to get the length of the word.
- The length might not be in the map, in which case you'll have to do something about that.
- If it is in the list then you'll have to do something slightly different.

And at the end you'll have to iterate through the map and print the result.

You can get details of how to work with maps here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: Thank you I am not jus looking for answers, I'm actively looking to learn by doing. Appreciate these steps and the link.

Comment: @MikeWortho You just started learning Java, are you sure your school allows you to use `Map`? You don't even need to use `Map` for this question. A simple loop + array can solve it. I think that's what the school wants to see - how to implement and not just using the API to solve your problems.

Comment: Map?  Every time I see a `Map<Integer, ...>` where the keys are all small, I wonder, why not an Array or an ArrayList?

Comment: GIven the poster's original question, I suspect that the jobs of dynamically extending an array is going to be beyond his present capabilities.  Similarly, even though ArrayList takes care of dynamically extending the list, you still have to interrupt your logic when a new index beyond the array size is encountered to append and initialise the intervening elements.  The four steps above would become 10 or 12, and would all over the place in terms of level-of-abstraction.